# Is there a way to avoid people to post code in comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, code-formatting

I see a [lot of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813650/python-print-statement-syntax-error-invalid-syntaximport-errorno-module-name/21813999?noredirect=1#comment33012310_21813999) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945473/receiving-mysql-value-to-flash?noredirect=1#comment33261217_21945473) where authors are posting *(long) code-only comments*. I think this behavior could be avoid, or at least handled. Here is my suggestions:

1. **Avoid this**: Check comments before posting. If some long code excerpt can be recognized, warn the user (might be **hard to implement** and too heavy) ;
2. **Give tools to handle this**: Allow users to flag a comment with the reason *"code-only comment"*. I think every flag comments reason today doesn't fit with this problem. For me, *not constructive* can't be used in this case (the comment might be constructive, but the code should be paste in the question, not in the comment itself).
3. **Force a minimum of non-code comment** (Something like 10 characters), as proposed in @cmaster answer

In addition, it could be nice if `backticks` content in comments can be limited to, let's say, 100 characters long. After, 80 characters, it's more than a function call or a simple expression, so it shouldn't be in comments.

Any ideas or opinions on this?

Comment: I don't get your second point. What is that supposed to achieve? Why not leave a comment for the OP, telling him to include the code into the post?

Comment: @Bart I'm doing that usually, but it takes time, have no references to the F.A.Q, with spelling/technical errors sometimes. Also, some authors doesn't understand and keep pasting in new comments... It would be nice if a comment was automatically posted to explain to the author why it's bad with links to the F.A.Q.

Comment: It's more of a problem for new users who are not aware of the edit button. More experienced users won't do that.

Comment: I sometimes leave a comment somewhat like "why not `some code`". I don't consider the code important enough to create an answer for it so I put it in a comment. Your suggestion would prevent this.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I agree with you. What I want is to avoid people who're writing long code comments (which is unreadable and affects the quality of the question). I like cmaster's idea in fact: force to have a minimum of non-code. But for that, the code needs to be around backticks, what new users don't use really often.

Comment: I don't see how that addresses my concerns though. The non-code part is maybe 10 characters long while the code part easily can be a lot more. Code in a comment isn't always unreadable in my opinion, it depends on what is written.

Comment: Most of the time this is used intelligently. Every once in a while, not so much; in those cases it's usually a new user and leaving a comment, asking them to edit the question instead of posting their code and sample data in a comment, is usually sufficient. I don't think forcing this behavior will have as much impact as you think, and it will eliminate the chance for people to use that markdown when it makes sense.

Comment: I have sometimes included short programs in comments to show how an answer was wrong;  this had a positive effect and the post was improved (these admittedly weren't code only, but they were a lot longer that 80 characters)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I won't deny that there are probably cases where this is a problem, however, in the tags that I'm active, I've never noticed this to be a problem.

I'm opposed to putting a limit on the length of code in comments, because sometimes you need to point something out that requires a bit of code to explain, especially when your point is about code structure.

What might be a good idea would be to set a minimum on the non-code contents of a comment, forcing people to give at least rudimentary explanations to why they post the code.

But, all in all, I don't really see this as a problem.